# How do I save to my home folder using gedit on MAC OS X?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions, gedit

I've just created a text file in gedit. I'm trying to save to a folder in my home folder and I'm getting the following error:

> You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file.
>
> Please check that you typed the location correctly.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: How did you invoke gedit? How did you specify the file to save to? From the console? Via the menu?

Comment: I have a alias in the dock that I call it from. 

I specified where to save via the menu.

Comment: Not clear yet. Please do an `ls -la` of the folder you want to save to and show us that.

Comment: It was my permissions on the root drive. I forget the command I found but I will look through my history.